# Auto refresh SQL Database Data that comes from an Excel Sheet

Tags: sql, excel, database, refresh

I have many living excel documents that I am trying to run reporting on.  I have the option to use a tool like Power Bi but wanted to know if it would be better to consolidate them into a SQL database prior to using that tool.

I wanted to know if I go and have a SQL database created and sorted based on these excel files, how often and will the data in SQL be refreshed.  Can it be a live update?

I am trying to create the best solution as these files are updated daily with new content. In Power Bi I can "Refresh Data" and pull in the latest information.  If I were to use SQL would I have to go and update SQL every time I want to update Power Bi?

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You would need a mechanism to update the data from excel into SQL Server. Be that VBA within the excel workbook, SSIS package run periodically, or an outside script to scrape the contents of the excel workbooks and store them. There isn't a way to "live update" the database from excel natively, like there is with Access.